# Узнать какая кнопка была нажата UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, button

Есть некоторый набор кнопок на странице, которые привязаны с одному методу ViewModel:

```
<Button Click="{x:Bind ViewModel.Foo} />
```

Необходимо как то определять, какая кнопка была нажата для вызова метода. Как вариант, я предполагал что будет передаваться параметр в метод Foo, с идентификатором нажатой кнопки. Но не совсем ясно, каким образом это сделать. Причем, кнопки динамически добавляются на страницу бесконечное количество раз. Какие есть варианты решения проблемы?

Comment: @Yami в UWP использование команд не обязательно для ViewModel. Можно обходиться привязкой x:Bind для методов и свойств. Возможно я чего-то недопонимаю, но нигде не видел использование команд, кроме WPF и UWP кода до введения x:Bind.

Comment: Используйте Binding к Command и задавайте CommandParameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете добавить в кнопку, при ее создании, в поле Tag, какую-нибудь информацию, которая вам поможет распознать кнопку и подписать кнопку на событие.
Например так:

```
  int countButton = 0;        
  while (countButton < 5)
  {
        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.Content = String.Format("Button {0}", countButton);
        btn.Click += MainPageViewModel.Instance.ButtonClick;
        btn.Tag = countButton;
        StackPanel.Children.Add(btn);
        countButton++;
  }
```

Класс ViewModel выглядит примерно так:

```
 public class MainPageViewModel
{
    private static MainPageViewModel instance;
    public static MainPageViewModel Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if(instance == null)
            {
                instance = new MainPageViewModel();
            }
            return instance;
        }
    }
    public void ButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("Кнопка нажата. Индекс: {0}", (sender as Button).Tag));
    }
}
```

p.s. Так же можно использовать Binding и привязывать команду Click к кнопке из кода. Ещё можно передавать параметр не через Tag, а например через CommandParameter при Binding команды (как писал [Андрей NOP](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/218063/%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B9-nop) в комментарии).